# How many make threads to use?

Tags: multithreading, efficiency, multi-core, make, build-system

When I (re-)build large systems on a desktop/laptop computer, I tell `make` to use more than one thread to speed up the compilation speed, like this:

```
$ make -j$[ $K * $C ]
```

Where `$C` is supposed to indicate the number of *cores* (which we can assume to be a number with one digit) the machine has, while `$K` is something I vary from `2` to `4`, depending on my mood.

So, for example, I might say `make -j12` if I have 4 cores, indicating to `make` to use up to 12 threads.

---

My rationale is, that if I only use `$C` threads, cores will be idle while processes are busy fetching data from the drives. But if I do not limit the number of threads (i.e. `make -j`) I run the risk to waste time switching contexts, run out of memory, [or worse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forkbomb). Let's assume the machine has `$M` gigs of memory (where `$M` is in the order of 10).

So I was wondering if there is an established strategy to choose the most efficient number of threads to run.

Comment: In many cases, the correct answer for number of threads is going to be the number of cores.  But the only way to know for sure is to run some tests, varying the number of threads until you find the sweet spot.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, I'll probably go and have a shell script compile with all sorts of settings over night, but I thought I'd ask if there is some knowledge about this out there.

Comment: many people also suggest $cores+1, so 1 compiler process reads from disk while 4 compile. A generic suggestion is hard, also depends on the code base (C++ template overuse vs. small compilation units with a few C functions), compiler chain (precompiled headers etc?) and the build structure (is it linking just one big thing in the end or multiple smaller things in between)

Comment: If you're seriously looking for performance, I'd suggest looking into setting up a RAM disk or some other method of alleviating your I/O. I don't think CPU utilization is your hot spot.

Comment: @TMN: How a RAM disk help? Linux is pretty good at caching stuff (you *do* mean the header files, right?), not to mention the drive cache. I would have to load everything into the shm first, either manually or by changing the build script (which would be utter overkill).

Comment: @bitmask: How big is your source tree?  If it will all fit, then just copy it to the RAM disk and kick off your make from there.  At least use one for a temporary directory (set $TMPDIR to point to it).

Comment: @TMN: My `$TMPDIR` points at `/tmp` which is a `tmpfs` ;)

Comment: try using vmstat to monitor the number of running/waiting/blocked processes. IIRC it will give you the numbers to determine if you need to increase or decrease the # of threads.

Comment: The only way to know is to test it write a shell script that iterates from 1 to say 50 and record what the wall clock time is for each. Maybe run each 5 times and take the average if you want to be a little more exact. In truth it probably won't matter too much set N = 8 or so and move on

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran a series of tests, building llvm (in Debug+Asserts mode) on a machine with two cores and 8 GB of RAM:

[image: compiling llvm time depending on number of jobs]

Oddly enough, it seems to climb until 10 and then suddenly drops below the time it takes to build with two jobs (one jobs takes about the double time, not included in the graph).

The minimum seems to be `7*$cores` in this case.

Comment: +1 for actual testing and not speculating.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Gentoo Linux (source-based distribution) and from my experience i can say that (with more or less recent hardware) `n*2 + x` is the best value. Let me explain this:

- `n*2`: Even slower CPU's have enough power to run 2 tasks at a time. most compile tasks are completed very fast.
- `+x` this number depends on your system (mainly memory and disk). If you have enough RAM and a fast disk, set `x=n`. However, this depends on the source code (Open Office, i'm looking at you!) and the used language (compiling C/C++ is very memory intensive).

However, you have to run some tests with some `-j` values to get the best number. Also, try to parallelize other steps of the build process: unpacking, running `configure` and so on.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with C++ at the moment, and my disks are not the fastest, I guess.

Comment: Then start with n*1.5 and increase it until the compile times stops decreasing (make sure you clean the disk cache/compile cache every time).
Also, think of using ccache (http://ccache.samba.org/) to speed up the compilation.